# Checkbox Binding

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting error message

> `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException`:
>   Invalid property '`produts[0]`' of
>   bean class [`java.util.HashMap`]: Bean
>   property '`produts[0]`' is not
>   readable or has an invalid getter
>   method: Does the return type of the
>   getter match the parameter type of the
>   setter?

when i perform following in jsp file

> ```
> <c:forEach items="${model.products}" var="prod"> varStatus="loop">
>   <tr>
>   <td align="center">
>     <form:checkbox path="produts[${loop.index}].selected"></form:checkbox>
>   </td>
>   <td><c:out value="${prod.description}"/> </td>
>   <td>$<c:out value="${prod.price}"/></td>
>   </tr>
> </c:forEach>
> ```

products is populated by `List<Product> getProducts();` in another class.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo to me:

```
produts[${loop.index}]
```

should be

```
products[${loop.index}]
```

Comment: It is a typo but i am getting same error message

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'products[0]' of bean class [java.util.HashMap]: Bean property 'products[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already in the forEach loop, why cant you just use `${prod.selected}` instead of `products[${loop.index}].selected`?